# Can the complement of a subset be realized as a limit or colimit?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two sets, and let $f:X\rightarrow Y$. Now consider the posets $(\mathcal{P}(X),\subseteq)$ and $(\mathcal{P}(Y),\subseteq)$ as categories. The induced functions $f^*$ (preimage function), $f_!$ (forward image function), and $f_*$ (the function which sends $B\subseteq X$ to the largest subset $C$ of $Y$ such that $f^*(C)\subseteq B$) can then be interpreted as functors between the said categories.

These functions also lead to a nice couple of adjunctions; namely, we have $f_!\dashv f^*\dashv f_*$

Since unions can be realized as colimits and intersections as limits, we get a nice categorical explanation for why $$f^*\left(\bigcup_{C\in\mathcal{C}}C\right)=\bigcup_{C\in\mathcal{C}}f^* (C)\quad\text{and}\quad f^*\left(\bigcap_{C\in\mathcal{C}}C\right)=\bigcap_{C\in\mathcal{C}}f^*(C)$$

However, we also have that $$f^*(Y-B)=X-f^*(B) \text{ for all } B\subseteq Y$$

This leads me to wonder the following:

> Can complements be realized as a limit or a colimit?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Complements are neither limits nor colimits, but as an exercise you might like to verify that any map between boolean algebras that preserves joins and meets must also preserve complements.

Comment: If $A \to B$ is a subobject (=monomorphism) in any well-behaved category, a complement is a maximal subobject $A' \to B$ such that $A \to B$ is disjoint to $A' \to B$, i.e. $A \times_B A'$ is initial. (I don't know if this is a standard definition.) Do exact functors preserve complements? I doubt that this is true, except for (see Zhen Lin's comment) boolean algebras for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by Zhen, complements cannot be described via limits or colimits. Nevertheless, we have the following interpretation:

Recall the notions of [monoidal categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+category) and [internal homs](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+hom) in monoidal categories.
In a monoidal poset, $\underline{\hom}(x,y)$ is the largest object such that $ \underline{\hom}(x,y) \cdot x \leq y$. If $y=0$ is an initial object (i.e. smallest element), then $\neg x := \underline{\hom}(x,0)$ is the largest object such that $(\neg x) \cdot x = 0$.

If $F : C \to D$ is a monoidal functor between closed monoidal posets, then there is a canonical morphism $F(\underline{\hom}(x,y)) \to \underline{\hom}(F(x),F(y))$ and $F$ is called [closed](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+functor) when this is an isomorphism. If $F$ is closed and $F(0)=0$, then we get $F(\neg x)=\neg F(x)$.

If $F$ has a left adjoint $L$, then $F$ is closed if and only if the "projection formula" $L(x F(y))=L(x) y$ holds. This is easy to check and for some reason is called [Frobenius reciprocity](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cartesian+closed+functor) at the nlab.

The monoidal functor  $f^* : (P(Y),\subseteq,\cap) \to (P(X),\subseteq,\cap)$ is closed, because we have $f_!(x \cap f^*(y))=f_!(x) \cap y$.

Comment: That was very enlightening. I really appreciate that your answers to seemingly closed questions are still pertinent and lead to new roads to investigate.